# Merge line with previous line

Tags: awk, sed

I'm trying to merge a line in a file with the previous line if the line begins with "set" for all instances. So if the file looks like this:

```
...<br>
...<br>
previous line<br>
set ...<br>
```

I want this (without knowing what the previous line is):

```
...<br>
...<br>
previous line set ...
```

I've tried this and other solutions found on google without success:

```
    sed 'H;1h;$!d;x;s/\nset//g' file

    awk 'BEGIN {RS=""}{gsub(/\n\set/,"", $0); print $0}' file
```

these just printed the lines without the "set" line and the file looked the same.

sed version is GNU 4.2.2

Comment: And what about the trailing `<br>`? And what do you mean with _without knowing what the previous line is_?

Comment: If the line begins with "set" replace the <br> after "previous line" with a space.
Meaning, I have no idea what the line before "set" is and it could differ from each instance.

Comment: So, what if the previous line does not end with `<br>`?, What if it is empty, for instance? Your problem is under-specified. You should probably think a bit more about what you really want, consider all possible cases, and clearly define the expected behavior in each of them.

Comment: It's never empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;s/\nset/ set/;ta;P;D' file
```

Make a two line buffer and replace the newline with a space if the second line begins with `set`.